# mac os equivalent of AVAudioSession setCategory ambient or mixWithOthers

Tags: macos, core-audio, avaudiosession

I have a simple mac os app, which is a wrapper around WebKit view. In that view I load 1 website. That website sometimes plays sounds.
I have noticed that if a standalone web browser (in my case Firefox) is opened along with my app I cannot hear sounds from my app until I switch to it or the web browser looses focus.

On iOS I would do something like:

```
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient)
```

to enable my app to mix audio with other apps audio.

What is equivalent on mac os? How can I make sure that audio from my app is played along other apps' audio?

Comment: did you find any equivalent for AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory for Mac OS ?

Comment: did you found something ?